# Highlight the weekday cells as day goes by automatically, Monday Thru Sunday. Today is Tuesday I want Tuesday to be highlighted, see image attached

Tags: html, css

Please see image below, I want the library hours to be highlighted automatically everyday.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvqhR.png

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript for that.

```
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDay(); //Returns 0-6 (sunday-saturday)
```

You can now add a highlighter class to the current day div depending on the `day` variable.